# How to POST a form to a REST endpoint with HTMX

Tags: htmx

I have a simple HTML form:

```
      <form id="contact" >
          <div>
              <label for="name">Name:</label>
              <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
          </div>
          <div>
              <label for="email">Email:</label>
              <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
          </div>
          <div>
              <label for="message">Message:</label>
              <textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea>
          </div>
          <input type="text" class="hidden" id="contact" name="webform_id"  value="contact">
          <button hx-post="{{ url('<front>') }}/webform_rest/submit?_format=json" type="submit">Send</button>
      </form>
      <div id="response"></div>
```

I got two responses back. The first is a POST with 302 error and then a GET with 405 error. The reponse for both requests is this:

```
{
    "message": "No route found for \"GET http://localhost:8080/web/webform_rest/submit\": Method Not Allowed (Allow: POST)"
}
```

On the first POST request, the object with values is normally sent to the backend. When I do the same POST with Postman the form submission goes through.

Thanks

Comment: Try moving hx-post to your form tag instead. Also looking at the error, it seems to be a backend issue. Are you sure it accepts the POST requests?

Comment: Yes. With postman the form submits to the backend. I have also trying moving the hx-post to the form tag with no success.

Comment: Can you provide the controller/view and url definitions please?